# Silly question about complex numbers - if its modulus is < 1, does raising it to higher exponents make it decrease to the real number 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value

Just playing around with the modulus definition doesn't really confirm that thought...

Is it true?

If |z| = |x+iy| < 1, is $$\lim_{n\to \infty} z^n = 0 ?$$

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Write $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $|r|<1$. Then $z^n=r^n e^{in\theta}$.

Can you finish?

Comment: Ah, of course :-( so the numbers do indeed limit to zero, as n goes to infinity.  Thanks so much for your quick response, @avid19.  Now back to my eigenvalues problem :-)  Have a great night,